# What do I do if a professor at a foreign university doesn't respond to my emails?

Tags: research-process, professorship, etiquette, email

I want to know about **appropriate actions to take when not receiving an e-mail reply from professors after 2 to 3 weeks of sending an e-mail**.

When writing my e-mails, I try to highlight questions and important points leaving other details in normal style to make the reader quickly understand what am I asking for. Additionally, I start the e-mail with Dear Professor , I conclude with a respectful salutation form and I proof read the text of the e-mails multiple times. I am sending e-mails to professors **asking them for a graduation project proposal**.

E-mails are sent to professors responsible for European or North American funded research projects.
Professors to whom I sent e-mails are from various institutions and countries (USA, Canada, Switzerland).
The **same problem is faced in previous occasions** when I needed to send e-mails for various purposes but I don't receive replies except for one or two times.
I tried twice sending reminders after a reasonable time (one to two weeks) of sending the first e-mail but no response is received!

**N.B:** if it's helpful to mention, my field is not covered by any research lab and not taught in any university in my country.
And this is what makes the problem more complicated!

Comment: I'm afraid I find your question unclear. Are you trying to find collaborators, a post-doc position, or to become a PhD or Master's student?

Comment: Thank you for your comment.
I am trying to reach researchers in bioinformatics (affiliated to foreign universities and research centers) in order to get an engineering graduation project proposal as I have previous research experience in the field.
So it's about getting involved in a research project as an undergraduate engineering student.
Is it clearer now ?

Comment: As this is about an undergraduate research project, and because the answer would be different for postgraduate research projects, then this question is off-topic.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I don't think so since I had previous research experience as a graduate student and research assistant !
I chose to do engineering studies for some reasons.
It results in an official status as an undergraduate student but in fact it's about doing research to enrich scientific literature and get a published paper (as I have done that before).
The issue here is about procedures to reach foreign professors for serious participation in research projects.

Comment: I have a hard time understanding this question. You are sending profs. in different countries requests for graduation projects? What answer are you hoping for?

Comment: @xLeitix I am expecting proposals from these professors to work with them on ongoing research projects related to my studies and research interests.

Comment: @ML_TN It is very ambitious to hope that profs. that you do not even know personally will offer you to work with them based on a cold email. The fact that they do not answer should presumably be interpreted as "not interested".

Comment: @xLeitix is there a more acceptable way to do that, knowing that I share some common research interests with some of these professors and it has been mentioned in the CV I attach to each e-mail ?

Comment: @ML_TN It is not the mail or the form that is a problem - it is simply that professors can't take up every student that "shares some interests with them", even if the student is not even enrolled in their university. Professors only have a finite amount of time.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers: Questions about getting involved in university-level research are __almost always__ on-topic, even if they're asked by people who are undergraduates (or even HS students).

Comment: I wonder how different this is to other sales pitches? Yes it's a professor but you can treat him/her just like any potential client/business partner/employer. If there's no reply in a few days just assume that he's not interested at your particular pitch. On the other hand he could be too busy for you at the time. In the latter case, you can try pinging him again when you have something new.

Comment: You formulate a question about email contact with professors. But from the comments, it seems you actually want to know how to get involved in a research field that is not present in your country. Maybe you'll get more helpful answers by explicitly asking that question.

Comment: If it is Don Knuth, you should at least wait a year before assuming he didn't read it.

Comment: @silvado The goal was to know how to proceed when I get no responses then comments led to the greater goal which is getting involved in Bioinformatics.
Don't you think that asking the question as you suggested will lead to the same responses (being recommended, going through the university and official channels, applying to a M.Sc or Ph.D program, having a highly cited Paper in the field ..) ?

Comment: @ML_TN : Your problem is that you don't know a way to get what you want. Learning to ask clear questions in writing on a website like this helps you. Describe your situation and what you want and if you are lucky someone has a helpful suggestion.

Comment: There are many people that do the same thing. Some professors get similar emails almost daily. After reading some emails, CVs and proposals like that (even I, as a PhD student, get some) it quickly becomes clear that most are 1) unrelated to the adressee's research, 2) sent by unqualified applicants and 3) sent to anybody with a university address. Experience that a couple of times and you delete the next one without opening it.

Comment: Not enough for a full answer, but as a professor, I can tell you that these letters are essentially spam to me. You're trying to cold-sell me something, just like the spam emails, and there are a lot of you. I have no idea what a graduation project proposal is. I can guess, but it sounds like something that involves a lot of work for me. If you want to know about something, I'll be more than happy to answer. One thing I can tell you doesn't get answers is someone in a different field clearly just fishing for assistanceship money.

Comment: Much of what you write is unclear. a) *"I email professors asking them for a graduation project proposal."* Does that you mean you suggest a project to them, or you ask them to suggest a project to you? To be funded by who, supervised by who, conducted in which country? b) First you say "graduate project", then you say "getting involved in a research project as an undergraduate engineering student". Which is it? c) You say  *"my field is not covered by any research lab and not taught in any university in my country"* Then it isn't your field; it's your proposed field, or desired field...

Comment: ...but since you're not even their graduate student, nor are you applying to be their grad student, why on earth would they respond? What form of response exactly are you even expecting? This sounds like a waste of both of your time. Much better to try to write a (draft) paper in that area, then try to submit it to publications which at least give decent review feedback.

Comment: Or, apply to their Bioinformatics courses as a grad student, already. Or else get a job in a Bioinformatics company and work your way up.

Answer (score 43):

Professors directly teaching might have some obligation to answer your email (some university have quality of service policies, ensuring that students receive feedback within a given number of working days), if it's related to their teaching.

Professors from partner universities might fall under the same obligations, if there is a mutual agreement. However, professors from other university have **no obligation whatsoever to answer you.**

Professors are usually very busy, among other things dealing with their own students, they might not have the time to deal with other students. If you are asking about a proposal and you do not receive an answer, you should assume by default that they are not interested. There is no much you can do, apart from contacting other professors, or asking your own professors to contact them.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. The research field is not available in my country (except for some individual attempts of some researchers) and this is the only available way to get an proposal.could sending a reminder be useful in this case ?

Comment: @ML_TN sending a reminder would be inappropriate - treat a non-response as the (reasonably expected) negative response. If they would be interested, then they would have replied, and a vast majority wouldn't be interested and should not be expected to waste time in replying to unsolicited requrests from unknown people, i.e.., spam.

Comment: @ML_TN: I agree with Peteris. If the research field is not available in your country, it should be the responsibility of your university, not you, to set up international collaborations and dedicated communication channels. Sending a reminder is likely to be useless.

Comment: @Peteris Thank you for the advice.What I understand form your comment that being unknown to these professors makes impossible to reach them !
As I asked above, how could I contact them if there are no professors in my university with the same background or reputation to make these foreign researchers answer a possible request from my professors ?

Comment: I know it's not the question you're asking, but have you considered doing a topic that is covered by staff at your university? or even changing university? Not only doing a remote supervision is not particularly easy, it might also be a problem for you to get properly assessed for your degree, if nobody there understands what you've been working on.

Comment: @CharlesMorisset I have approached some professors of my university to seek advice about the topic (even though they are not fully knowledgeable about it nor involved in it) and they encouraged me to go for it !

Comment: While they're not obligated to answer, ignoring emails is as jerky as ignoring someone who walks up to you and begins talking.  It's not hard to say 'no'.

Comment: @horsehair: If the number of emails you receive is less or equal than the number of people walking up to you and beginning talking, you're lucky!

Comment: @horsehair: Do you respond to each of the e-mails that offer you "VIP Dating", Medication of various sorts, or a credit?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper I disagree that serious inquiries from those who have chosen someone, by name and reputation, to contact are akin to spam.  Do you really view students that way?

Comment: @horsehair: I am not a professor - but I regularly receive e-mails that start with something like "Dear Professor <my name>". After that, the people often write they have chosen me specifically (when I ask my colleagues, it almost always turns out they wrote the same text to them), listing a set of keywords that roughly match the topics my whole department is centered around, and then either ask for some assistance or ideas for some student project, as if I were their teaching personnel, or ask for a job "in [my] team", as if I were in a position to hire people. That is very much like spam.

Comment: @horsehair: Not to forget the mails whose authors start by describing they have read one of my papers that I published several years back, and now ask me to tutor their student project (when they are obviously not students at my university) in a totally different topic than the paper they have mentioned.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - Fine, but this does not seem to be the case for the OP.  Since you seem to be able to get a sense of what is and is not a legitimate request (and what is spam, as you previously mentioned), ignore those and give the serious folks at least one reply to tell them you aren't interested.

Comment: **Please avoid extended conversations in the comments, and transfer to the chat.**

Answer (score 35):

I get emails like this all the time and never reply.  I can't imagine that anyone would give you a positive response, and I don't think there is anything you can do that will result in you getting what you want.

I think that my policies for responding to email are pretty typical.
Aside from "professional business stuff" (e.g. invitations to speak, referee requests, inquiries from the media, etc), I generally only respond to emails from strangers in the following situations.

1. Technical questions about my papers (or related things, e.g. my answers on math overflow).  These always get a response, though sometimes I can take a little while if I'm particularly busy (e.g. when traveling).
2. Mathematical questions.  I'll always answer these if they are close to my research interests and are at a high level, and otherwise it depends on my mood.  The speed is similar to questions of type 1.
3. Questions from students at Rice.  These always get some kind of response, usually very quickly (sometimes that response is a request that they come to my office and chat).  I'll also usually respond to questions from students who have some kind of indirect connection with me (e.g. I'll respond to questions from students of my collaborators).
4. Inquiries about our graduate program.  For specific question, I'll usually quickly respond.  For things that seem more like requests to work with me, if they sound serious then they get a very short reply with a link to the webpage saying how to apply to our PhD program (and a sentence about how I don't take students until they have been accepted and passed their quals).  Sometimes they sound ridiculous (e.g. someone who has an engineering background and is clearly emailing everyone they can find on the internet), and they get no response.

Other than that, I just don't have the time.  I have enormous amounts of stuff that I have to do that is directly related to teaching (at Rice; I'm not paid to teach anyone else) and research.  I'm sorry that you can't get help from your own university, but sadly there just isn't anything that I can do about that.

Comment: `+1` for first paragraph of your answer and *[...] otherwise it depends on my mood.*

Comment: @Andy Putman 
Thank you Professor Putman for your answer.
What do you suggest as a solution to overcome Professors' rejection of such e-mails ?
I want to approach professors working on Bioinformatics who are concentrated in anglo-saxon universities.
This continuous rejection, even though being enthusiastically willing to participate in the research efforts is frustrating.
Additionally, being a student from the North African region will reduce my chances to get an answer to zero ! 
How are we supposed to work with renowned scientists while the unique available way to communicate is cut-off?

Comment: @ML_TN : I don't think there is anything you can do (the only thing I can think of is applying to graduate schools abroad in the usual manner).  You are asking people to do a large amount of unpaid work to help you.  It just isn't going to happen.  And it isn't being from North Africa -- you would get a similar response to unsolicited requests like this no matter where you lived.

Comment: @AndyPutman usually when someone will be supervised in a funded research project Ph.D students or other group members will do the supervision and the Professor (responsible for the project) won't generally get involved in this task and he will get later all the praise when his name will appear on the paper containing the research results.
I am just trying to reach the director to get me in the group and give me a general description of my task and I am not asking for more than that.
**What about "enthusiastic students could contact me on this e-mail" that we could find on professors pages?**

Comment: @ML_TN You are truly missing the point. What you are asking for is *never* going to happen. You are not a student attending the school where these people teach. You are not a student of a colleague. You are a complete stranger with no apparent credentials. It will *never* happen. As I see it you have three choices to get noticed: 1) Go invent something/write a paper in bioinformatics that gets everyone's attention, 2) change schools where there is a good program (and that only slightly increases your chances as there is a *lot* of competition), or 3) pay someone a lot up front to help you.

Comment: @ML_TN : As par says, this simply isn't how academia works.  Period.

Comment: (and if they have something asking students to contact them for positions, almost certainly they mean students at their own universities; if you want to work with someone, apply to go to graduate school at their university)

Comment: I work(ed) and live with a number of academics (aka my family and friends) and agree with the above with one caveat; it is possible (but not easy at all) to get responses to requests from professors whom you do not already work with by "networking" with them at conferences and impressing them in that situation. This method is hard work, costs a great deal in conference fees, and has a very low success rate. @AndyPutman has given you by far the best advice (+1)

Comment: _What do you suggest as a solution to overcome Professors' rejection of such e-mails?_ — I suggest a stiff drink, a walk on the beach, and an adjustment of your expectations.

Comment: @ML_TN One way that *might* work: create an actual, original, decent piece of research, write it up, put it on arXiv and pitch it to the people you write to (mail only such that are very close to your topic!). *If* they open your mail and *if* they skim the article and *if* they like it, you have given an indication that working with you *may* be fruitful. Under these circumstances, you *may* get a reply. (I've seen it happen. Once.) Be interesting, not desperate.

Answer (score 18):

It sounds like you are e-mailing strangers and asking them to tell you what to do. This seems almost certain to fail.

Also, I don't know what a "graduation project proposal" is -- keep in mind that these professors don't know and don't care what the requirements of your university are. They *might* be willing to help you with their scientific expertise, but you should not ask them for help with anything that doesn't *directly* relate to what their expertise is in, or where it's not clear what exactly you are asking for.

Here is an e-mail that *might* get a reply.

> Dear Prof. X,
>
> I am a student at University Y where I am interested in bioinformatics. I have to complete a senior research project [... brief details]
>
> One topic I was considering was XYZ. In particular, I was thinking I might try to investigate the effect of ABC on DEF under conditions GHI. [Note: **do your own homework here, this should be something intelligent** and then they might be willing to provide helpful input] I hope I can ask you two questions: In the first place, do you believe that such an approach is feasible?
>
> If so, since University Y doesn't have much in the way of resources, do you know where I might seek guidance as I work on this?
>
> Thank you very much.

Comment: Thank you for the proposed draft.
The template of sent emails are generally as follows:
- Saying a word about my current studies
- Asking for an opportunity to participate in a specific project (that I give the exact name) in which the professor is involved in 
- Asking for a proposal in the field (as a graduation project proposal) that he is specialized in
- Talking in a small paragraph that I have done previous work in the field without available resources (lack of funding and supervision)
- a sentence about the attached C.V
It's almost the same template that you are suggesting

Comment: @ML_TN No no no. Not only it's not the same template Anonymous is suggesting; it's very far from it. It's not even remotely close. Detach yourself from your current ideas about what to do, and then reread the comments and answers here.

Answer (score 13):

Too long for comments: both the earlier answers are very apt.

The original poster's comment to the later answer reveals a misapprehension about how things work, and the relative work-load to accomplish certain things.

First, cold-calling is a bad start on anything... unless it is extremely polite, is clearly completely specific to the individual addressed E.g., I respond badly, or, simply, not at all to emails with no "greeting" whatsoever, or do not address me (politely) by name, and/or that give no indication of anything specific to *me* or my actual work, etc. My reasoning is that I should spend no more effort on a response than is visible in the initial email... especially if I'm being asked to do someone a favor.

Second, asking to participate in a project whose existence is unknown makes the inquiry sound very spam-y, so will invariably get a bad reaction. Already it'd be an uphill battle to get a spot on a project whose existence was known and relevant... since most likely there are more people wanting such spots than there are spots available. Again, you should "do your homework" about existing projects, and their specifics.

Third, asking for a "proposal" is asking for quite a lot, in fact. That is, a coherent, viable, state-of-the-art proposal is something that takes quite a while to craft, and has considerable value of various sorts. In many subjects, the writing-up of such is a major activity. Such things would not be donated to *anyone*, much less cold-callers, much less cold-callers who send "reminders".

... and this isn't "ungenerousness", it's that many academic research situations are very competitive, especially for funding, and people work full-bore to get that funding, ... leaving not a lot of energy left over to donate to unknown people.

Even if you're cold-calling, giving no or scant information about yourself (except that you're looking for participation in a project in subject X) gives the responder little ground to respond *reasonably*... and I, for one, am disinclined to go through several emails to extract information that should have been available up-front, etc.

In summary, there simply isn't any powerful way for you to induce responses of the sort that'd directly help you in the way you wish, understandable though your wishes are, and as unfortunate as your local situation may be. Some different path will most likely have to be taken.

Comment: Is starting an e-mail with Dear Professor <name of the professor> considered as a "cold-calling" ?
Second, the projects I've asked to join are existing and they are regrouping many participants of the same or different universities !
Well, I start the e-mail with presenting my self and I speak later about my work in few words and I attach a CV to the e-mail: isn't that enough as pieces of information ?

Comment: It's better than spam to write "Dear Professor <name>", but still "cold-calling", in that you have no prior acquaintance, and you are asking for something. Attaching a CV is appropriate. Good that you check projects exist and are relevant. Still, people do get many such requests, and many take the view that an inquiry cannot/does not create the burden of response. I myself try to give a brief "thanks for your interest, but sorry, ...", but, mercifully, I don't have to spend too much time doing this each day. Others may feel more pressured, or feel that a brief turn-down won't help anything.

Comment: So what to do if sending reminders is not recommended ?
The topic (Bioinformatics) I want to work on is attracting attention of researchers in my country but they are no institutions to recommend or encourage people willing to get in touch and work with prominent researchers abroad.

Comment: For the researchers abroad to take inquiries seriously, it would invariably work better (even if not easily accomplishing all desired goals) to have _institutions_ (such as your university) do the inquiring in some quasi-official way. This might not necessarily help you yourself, individually or immediately, but would _surely_ help you and your peer group _collectively_, and in the long run.

Answer (score 7):

I agree with other respondents that you cannot expect unknown professors to respond to your emails.

Could you join an online community (email list) for your area of research interest?  After lurking long enough to understand its culture, could you send a post explaining your situation (being interested in the topic and having nobody to discuss it with in your country) and ask if someone would be willing to comment on your proposal?  Alternately, you could send your proposal to the list (although be prepared for it to be torn to shreds).  The administrator of the list may be able to advise you on what is appropriate.

Good luck!

Answer (score 5):

As the other answers already tell you, asking for a project proposal is asking for a very big favor, such that cold calling isn't likely to work.

The following piece of information is missing from the discussion as of now, however: many established researchers receive many cold-call requests for doing an internship with them. It is common practice in some countries to have them included in the students' curricula, and thus, it is not uncommon for students to aim high and try to get one at good schools abroad. Quite often, these mails are not very well targeted and researchers getting many of them are quite quick at pressing the "delete" key here.

Your request for a thesis topic/proposal may very easily be **seen** to fall into this category, even if it does not! Because such a request is so uncommon, people may expect that you would be asking for a (possibly paid) internship or (paid) PhD position in the second mail, and thus may not want to risk to be embarrased that they invested time on the matter if it turns out later that their suspicion was correct. So hitting the delete button quickly is a safe course of action for them.

I second the commenter's suggestion to ask your institution to build the necessary bridges for you. Does your institution already have a scheme for spending a semester abroad? Perhaps you can consider actually doing that?

Answer (score 2):

One additional factor which I think may be useful at least as secondary background information: This sounds a lot like you are trying to bypass the regular admission process.  You should start by finding out what it takes to become a student at their Department and follow the same enrollment process as everybody else.  If your background and skills are a good fit, you could find yourself in a project even as a junior student (but this is arguably a very optimistic outlook).

Answer (score 0):

I try to be responsive as much as possible, even if I cannot help. However, if I see that the person clearly has no idea what I am working on, tags on some keywords that seem to fit my profile or similar, and I am under time pressure, I won't respond. They haven't spent the effort finding out who they are addressing, and cannot expect effort of politeness in return.

Sometimes, I get what is effectively advice request from students from another university. If they work on something I am interested in, have done good work and bring something to the table, I consider this a collaboration across institutions, and I am happy to engage in it to some extent. However, if it is clearly a supervision request with no benefit to research that I am able to productively carry out, I am not prepared to invest my department's resources (i.e. my time) for this. Supervising my local students, for which I am paid, takes precedence.

I do give, however, brief advice where I can help with a little effort. This should not be extended into a back-and-forth discussion, to not abuse the time of the responder.