# How to respond when Professor do not reply to your earlier mail?

Tags: etiquette, email

Recently, I asked a professor to give me some references about a field that I can read about during my semester so that when it is time for a project, I can know the prerequisites of the subject. In reply, the professor said that we can meet and talk about the possible solutions when you are on campus. I was on campus, and so I asked him to schedule a meet, but he did not reply after that.

This sounds like this [question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/101834/133008), but it's not quite so. It seems to me that not getting a reply is kind of expected. What I'm asking:

*How can I respond to this considering he did not reply to my earlier request?* The possible reason as it seems to me, is that he forgot. Should I just repeat what I said earlier? Or should I say, "Excuse me, please reply to this"?

Comment: The usual polite approach is to assume that they didn't receive your previous message.  Something like "I'm resending this in case it went to your spam folder; I hope that we can meet soon."

Comment: "Excuse me, please reply to this" seems very aggressive.

Answer (score 1):

**Send a reminder.** Sending a reminder is totally fine after one week has passed since the original e-mail. A typical wording would be along the lines of:

> Just a brief reminder. Did you have the chance to look into this?

..to which you append your previous e-mail. The natural way to do this in most e-mail programs is to click the "Reply" button on your own e-mail.